# java.lang.RuntimeException : no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'

Tags: json, cassandra, runtimeexception, apache-storm

I have written a simple storm topology where spout reads data in json format. My first bolt parses the json and sends a particular value to the word counter bolt which writes the data into Cassandra.

Please suggest me the changes.Thanks in Advance !!

Main Topology:

```
public class TopologyMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //Topology definition
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
    builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer())
        .shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
    //builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),1)
        //.fieldsGrouping("word-normalizer", new Fields("sentence1"));
    builder.setBolt("word-counter1", new WordCounter(),1)
    .shuffleGrouping("word-normalizer", "stream1");
    /*builder.setBolt("word-counter2", new WordCounter1(),1)
    .shuffleGrouping("word-normalizer", "stream2");*/


    //Configuration
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put("wordsFile", "/home/raremile/git/infer-search-realtime/InferlyticsConsumerStorm/src/main/resources/log_tenlaz_10Jun.json");
    conf.setDebug(false);
    //Topology run
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("Getting-Started-Toplogie", conf, builder.createTopology());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //cluster.shutdown();
}
}
```

WordNormalizerBolt:

```
public class WordNormalizer extends BaseBasicBolt {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public void cleanup() {}

/**
 * The bolt will receive the line from the
 * words file and process it to Normalize this line
 * 
 * The normalize will be put the words in lower case
 * and split the line to get all words in this 
 */
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String sentence = input.getString(0);

    String sentence1 = null;
   // String sentence2 = null;
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(sentence);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*try {
        sentence2 = obj.getJSONObject("envelope").getString("sessionId");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    try {
         sentence1 = obj.getJSONObject("body").getString("searchTerm");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        sentence1 = sentence1.trim();
       // sentence2 = sentence2.trim();

        if(!sentence1.isEmpty()){
            sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase();
            //collector.emit(new Values(sentence1));
            collector.emit("stream1", new Values(sentence1));
            System.out.println("In Normalizer : "+sentence1);
        }
       /* if(!sentence2.isEmpty()){
           // sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase();
            //collector.emit(new Values(sentence1));
            collector.emit("stream2", new Values(sentence2));
            System.out.println("In Normalizer : "+sentence2);
        }*/
    }



/**
 * The bolt will only emit the field "word" 
 */
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    //declarer.declare(new Fields("sentence1"));
    declarer.declareStream("stream1", new Fields("sentence1"));
    //declarer.declareStream("stream2", new Fields("sentence2"));
}
}
```

Word CounterBolt:

```
public class WordCounter extends BaseBasicBolt {

Integer id;
String name;
Map<String, Integer> counters;

/**
 * At the end of the spout (when the cluster is shutdown
 * We will show the word counters
 */
@Override
public void cleanup() {

}

/**
 * On create 
 */
@Override
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
    this.counters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.name = context.getThisComponentId();
    this.id = context.getThisTaskId();
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.229").build();
    Session session = cluster.connect("query");
    String query = "CREATE TABLE queryNewUpdateCounterTerm(item text PRIMARY KEY, "
             + "count counter );";
    session.execute(query);
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {}


@Override
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String str = input.getString(0);
    /**
     * If the word dosn't exist in the map we will create
     * this, if not We will add 1 
     */

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.229").build();
    Session session = cluster.connect("query");
    String update = "UPDATE queryNewUpdateCounterTerm SET count = count + 1 " +
            "where item = \'"+str+"\';";
    session.execute(update);
    /*try{
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("storm");

    final DBCollection table = db.getCollection("words");



    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();


    if(!counters.containsKey(str)){
        counters.put(str, 1);
        dbObject.put("searchItem",str);
        dbObject.put("count",1);
        System.out.println(dbObject);
        table.insert(dbObject);
    }else{
        Integer c = counters.get(str) + 1;
        counters.put(str, c);
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("searchItem", str);
        BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();

        documentDetail.put("count", c);
        BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
        updateObj.put("$set", documentDetail);
        System.out.println(updateObj);
        table.update(query, updateObj);
    }
     }catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();            }
     System.out.println("In Counter : ");*/

    System.out.println("In Counter : ");
}
}
```

**error**

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3439$fn__3451$fn__3498.invoke(executor.clj:748) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:35) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at bolts.WordCounter.execute(WordCounter.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3439$tuple_action_fn__3441.invoke(executor.clj:633) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3362.invoke(executor.clj:401) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1445.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:101) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
... 1 common frames omitted
16262 [Thread-9-word-counter1] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3439$fn__3451$fn__3498.invoke(executor.clj:748) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:35) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at bolts.WordCounter.execute(WordCounter.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3439$tuple_action_fn__3441.invoke(executor.clj:633) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3362.invoke(executor.clj:401) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1445.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:101) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
... 1 common frames omitted
16334 [Thread-9-word-counter1] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4693$fn__4694.invoke(worker.clj:491) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__3272$fn__3273.invoke(executor.clj:240) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:473) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: which cassandra version you are using ? might be related with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2488

Comment: I am using  Cassandra 2.1.5

Comment: what's the output of printing the `update` variable ? its actually complaining about a parse error

Comment: When i run this program it runs for few minutes and updates the db perfectly.But after few seconds it starts erroring out.

Output is **TERM** in string and **COUNT** in integer

It looks like this

abc 10